# incorrect result of queries vb.net and microsoft access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have queries using microsft access 2007 and vb.net. If I tried to execute it in microsoft access  manually then the result was fine. But using code in vb.net I the result I've got was all the same

Please help...

here is the code

```
"SELECT " & _
   "amount as sss_loan_amount," & _
   "(SELECT amount FROM pr_deduction " & _
       "INNER JOIN pr_employee_deduction " & _
       "ON pr_deduction.deduction_id = pr_employee_deduction.deduction_id  " & _
       "WHERE pr_deduction.deduction_type = 'pag-ibig' " & _
       "AND employee_id = 60) as pagibig_amount," & _
   "(SELECT amount FROM pr_deduction " & _
       "INNER JOIN pr_employee_deduction " & _
       "ON pr_deduction.deduction_id = pr_employee_deduction.deduction_id " & _
       "WHERE pr_deduction.deduction_type = 'cash Advance' " & _
       "AND employee_id = 60) as cashadvance_amount " & _
"FROM pr_deduction " & _
"INNER JOIN pr_employee_deduction " & _
"ON pr_deduction.deduction_id = pr_employee_deduction.deduction_id " & _
"WHERE pr_deduction.deduction_type = 'sss loan' " & _
"AND employee_id = 60 "
```

in access the result are the ff

```
sss_loan_amount  pagibig_amount  cashadvance_amount     
1100             1200            1300
```

using code below the output are the same "1100" . I couldn't trace why.

```
MsgBox(reader("sss_loan_amount"))
MsgBox(reader("pagibig_amount"))
MsgBox(reader("cashadvance_amount"))
```

Comment: I have greatly edited the sql statement for readability, so if start or end quotes or line continuation characters are missing, you might like to look at the original.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand your question, and as no one has answered, I may not be the only one.

Comment: I think what he's saying is that the MsgBox() statements are all returning the data from the first field, not from each of the three fields. It's not an Access question, so I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with the access data types but it's possible that it doesn't like using strings as field identifiers. Try using `reader(0)`, `reader(1)`, etc... Also, what happens if you use an incorrect field name `reader("xxx")`.

Failing that, can you provide the code showing how reader() is populated.

Comment: hi basiclife I posted the vb code using answer my question because I couldn't post it using add comment. thanks

Comment: Did you try @BasicLife's suggestion of reader(0), reader(1)... ?

Comment: I already tried but almost the same output, it will give 1100 for all result

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vb code

```
  Public Sub SETCONNECTION()
      dataCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=D:\system_development\aim_global\timekeeping_payroll\timekeeping_payroll\bin\data\timekeeping_payroll.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=")
      dataCon.Open()
  End Sub

  Public Sub ReadSQL(ByVal sSQL As String)
      Try
      SETCONNECTION()
      CMD = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, dataCon)
      reader = CMD.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

     Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

     End Try
   End Sub
```

here is the vb code to get the result and show it.

```
 Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "SELECT amount as sss_loan_amount,(SELECT amount FROM pr_deduction INNER JOIN pr_employee_deduction ON pr_deduction.deduction_id = pr_employee_deduction.deduction_id WHERE pr_deduction.deduction_type = 'pag-ibig' AND employee_id = 60) as pagibig_amount,"

sSQL += " (SELECT amount FROM pr_deduction INNER JOIN pr_employee_deduction ON pr_deduction.deduction_id = pr_employee_deduction.deduction_id WHERE pr_deduction.deduction_type = 'cash Advance' AND employee_id = 60) as cashadvance_amount "

sSQL += " FROM pr_deduction INNER JOIN pr_employee_deduction ON pr_deduction.deduction_id = pr_employee_deduction.deduction_id WHERE pr_deduction.deduction_type = 'sss loan' AND employee_id = 60 "

ReadSQL(sSQL)

reader.Read()



MsgBox(RVC(reader("sss_loan_amount")))

MsgBox(RVC(reader("pagibig_amount")))

MsgBox(RVC(reader("cashadvance_amount")))
```

Comment: Hi, for your reference, the correct way to add the code is to edit your question, not post an answer. If I had enough rep, I'd edit it for you but I don't.

Comment: Can you clarify what the call to RVC() is for? If you put a breakpoint on the line after reader.Read(), what does the debugger tell you about the reader object? Does it tell you how many rows/columns (fields/records) are present? Also, you didn't mention in your comment to my question - What happens if you use a field name which doesn't exist? lastly, can you clarify the exact type of the reader object? eg is it an `OleDb.OleDbDataReader`

Comment: Assuming it's an OleDb.OleDbDataReader, it should have the following fields... `FieldCount`, `HasRows`, `VisibleFieldCount`. You should also be able to explicitly call `reader.item(0)`, `reader.item(1)`, `reader.item("sss_loan_amount")`, etc... Do these give different results?